# Capture image in custom camera in iOS without save image in Gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios8, camera, photo-gallery

I want use custom camera and due to some security purpose i do not want to save capture images in my gallery.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please give us its solution I'm also finding such kind of think

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImage *imgTaken;               
   NSString *docsDir,*imgNewPath;  
   NSData *imgData;  
   NSFileManager *filemgr;     
  dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
  docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0]; 





  -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info   
        {  
        imgTaken = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];  
        imgNewPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name your image"]];
        imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgTaken);  
        [imgData writeToFile:imgNewPath atomically:YES];  
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
    }
```

i hope it will help you.